# How to get and update Django object in one query?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

To optimize a lot my database I would like to make as less as possible any query.

I'm trying to get an object, increment the field "count_limit" and make an If statement after on the Customer instance.

To achieve it I've made this query who worked well.

```
Customer.objects.filter(user=user).update(count_limit=F('count_limit') + 1)
```

So after this query, count_limit has been incremented by 1 as I wanted.
When I'm trying to get the Customer instance as a result of this query, it returns "1".

Is it possible to make both, update the instance and get it as a return object ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) method will return the number of updated rows. If you are using Postgres, then you can use the [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html) clause with the raw query.

```py
query = 'UPDATE customer SET count_limit=(customer.count_limit + 1) WHERE customer.user_id=%s returning *'
updated_obj = Customer.objects.raw(query, [user.id])
```

I don't know if this can be achieved by ORM, but suggestions will be appreciated.

Make sure that the table name in raw query is correct. If you haven't definer `db_table` in the meta class of your model, then by default it will be `myapp_model`.

And to prevent SQL injection, from the Docs:

> Do not use string formatting on raw queries or quote placeholders in
>   your SQL strings!

Follow [Docs on raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)